# Bootstrap dependency wicket, disable preset styling for some pages

Tags: java, spring, twitter-bootstrap, apache, wicket

I've added `wicketstuff-openlayers3-bootstrap`to my dependency list in `pom.xml`, which is some prebuilt components to use in openlayers3 with bootstrap. I have a problem that this dependency is changing the styling to all my pages, when I only want it to be used for only one page. Is it possible to limit a dependency only to be used for one file, or to disable the preset styling coming from bootstrap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to tell Wicket Bootstrap to not append the Bootstrap resources automatically to all pages: `IBootstrapSettings#setAutoAppendResources(false)`.

See https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/blob/2ee370bc49e2735877e1dd06a2f099a0789bf3c8/bootstrap-core/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/core/settings/IBootstrapSettings.java#L118

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap by default appends its resrouces to all pages. To disable this you will need to override it using. `IBootstrapSettings#setAutoAppendResources(false)`